# ASP.NET Core, Microsoft Account Login & AADSTS70001

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-account

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Account Login in my application. I tried it some years ago and `MSAccount` was always difficult to use because of some restrictions (localhost development etc.) - but it seems this is now possible.

I used this [**docs.microsoft guide**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins) and created a brand new ASP.NET Core Application & used the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.MicrosoftAccount NuGet package`.

When I click the Microsoft Login Button I'm redirected to the login.microsoft page:
(I removed the clientId & state)

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=....&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44320%2Fsignin-microsoft&state=....
```

Now I'm entering my personal Microsoft Account login information (e.g. foobar@hotmail.com)

Next I will be redirected to the "Enter password" page:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=....&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44320%2Fsignin-microsoft&state=...&login_hint=...&ui_locales=en-US&display=page&uaid=21775924944348cfb0f84a8c0af34259&issuer=mso&tenant=common&msproxy=1
```

After I type in my password and click sign-in I'm redirected back to my application with a big `"unhandled exception occurred"`

> Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: BadRequest;Headers: Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache
>   Date: Wed, 12 Apr 2017 06:57:18 GMT
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   P3P: CP="DSP CUR OTPi IND OTRi ONL FIN"
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
>   Set-Cookie: esctx=AQABAAAAAABnfiG-mA6NTae7CdWW7QfdD3JzLSDc3ZvXogRmsm6vmOSSFDequk0G6rQQlFmOrTaEnzNYcStgzBDm04fNESerSjI3ytHGCzBQkCrOZSy5bYq5CrARZbRfx_oh8wbkqVaK8c1Q6VYyxN43noSOCpff72HxLg9fgB7t4DIPl7QLSjsFVmVxxeN4Xs06bT40AxogAA; domain=.login.microsoftonline.com; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, x-ms-gateway-slice=004; path=/; secure; HttpOnly, stsservicecookie=ests; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   x-ms-request-id: de0960ca-282b-4832-8d79-7e544fb30500
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   ;Body: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"AADSTS70001: Application with identifier '000000004C1CEB08' was not found in the directory 9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad\r\nTrace ID: de0960ca-282b-4832-8d79-7e544fb30500\r\nCorrelation ID: f204ae6b-8169-4b2c-8af6-902f1c62b79d\r\nTimestamp: 2017-04-12 06:57:19Z","error_codes":[70001],"timestamp":"2017-04-12 06:57:19Z","trace_id":"de0960ca-282b-4832-8d79-7e544fb30500","correlation_id":"f204ae6b-8169-4b2c-8af6-902f1c62b79d"};
>   ```

In the past we did some Azure Active Directory / Office 365 development and my MSAccount might also be inside one or two different Azure Active Directories, but my goal is just to login with my **personal** Microsoft Account, so I'm not sure why the error points to some AAD directory.

Any hint how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was related to my app registration. Under [this](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList) URL you can create to different application types - make sure you use a **converged application** and **not(!) a Live SDK application**.

The application ID should be in form of a guid (the live SDK applications app ids are not guids).

Answer (score 2):

As below image your ClientSecret is under "Value"(not under "Secret ID"):

[image]

and As below image your ClientId is "Application (client) ID"(not "Directory (tenant) ID"):

[image]